# Why cUrl Response Content Json Data Containing Question Mark in String

Tags: php, json, http, curl, response

I am using PHP cUrl for getting json data from url. The response is ok, but some value of properties is showing question mark inside string. Why that happen?
I have the screenshot:

[image]

The codes i am using now:

$url = 'https://shopee.co.id/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=71635103&shop_id=2768984';

```
Method:

public function getProductDetails($url)
{
    $csrftoken = $this->cookies['csrftoken'];
    $cookies   = $this->cookiesString;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "shopee_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "shopee_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: */*',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Cookie: ' . $cookies,
        'Host: shopee.co.id',
        'if-none-match-: *;gzip',
        'if-none-match-: *',
        'Referer: https://shopee.co.id/Canon-EOS-70D-Kit-18-200mm-IS-Built-In-Wifi-i.2768984.71635103',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
        'x-api-source: pc',
        'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest',
        )
    );

    //echo '<pre>' . print_r($headerSent, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close( $ch );

    return $result;
}
```

I hope you guys help me this problem. thanks. :)

================================================================
 I got the solution...

I have changed the request method with "OPTIONS"
That fixed my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set encoding like this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: I repeatedly request with same url.. and the thing happened... but i wait some minutes... The json data show normal without question mark... How can that happen?